# MongoDB Java find nested object using regex

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I'm using the MongoDB driver to create the query below. I'm just wondering what's the difference between the functionality of the two codes:

Returns 0; **address:{"houseBldgNum"}**

```
db.students.count({ "studentName" : { "$regex" : "(.+)?JAN(.+)?" , "$options" : "i"} , "address" : {"houseBldgNum" : { "$regex" : "(.+)3(.+)?" , "$options" : "i"} }})
```

Returns 2; **address.houseBldgNum**

```
db.students.count({ "studentName" : { "$regex" : "(.+)?JAN(.+)?" , "$options" : "i"} , "address.houseBldgNum" : { "$regex" : "(.+)3(.+)?" , "$options" : "i"} })
```

Data:

```
{
  "studentName":"JAN M",
  "address":{
    "houseBldgNum":"3"
  },
  "studentName":"JAN K",
  "address":{
    "houseBldgNum":"35"
  }
}
```

I'm expecting that the two codes should return the same result, but its not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data you have given above,`"houseBldgNum":"3"` is a document within a document.

```
{
  "studentName":"JAN M",
  "address":{
    "houseBldgNum":"3"
  }
```

To access a single document value it is enough to give the key value pair.Like this `address:{"houseBldgNum"}`

But to access the document within a document u need to use .(dot) notation to access the inner fields.

So the correct syntax is to use `address.houseBldgNum`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As you see in the code I used `"address" : {"houseBldgNum" : { "$regex" : "(.+)3(.+)?" , "$options" : "i"} }` not just `address:{"houseBldgNum"}`

Comment: `"address" : {"houseBldgNum"` and `address:{"houseBldgNum"}` both are same in terms of accessing the key-values. U should use `address.houseBldgNum` to access the value within `"address":{
    "houseBldgNum":"35"
  }`
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/ read Dot notation under this link . This will help you....

Answer (score 0):

The second query works as "address" is a nested json document embedded inside the top level document. If you want to access nested documents then you need to follow the notation "address.houseBldgNum".

Excerpts from MongoDB docs:

**Dot Notation**
MongoDB uses the dot notation to access the elements of an array and to access the fields of a subdocument.

To access an element of an array by the zero-based index position, concatenate the array name with the dot (.) and zero-based index position, and enclose in quotes:
'array.index'
To access a field of a subdocument with dot-notation, concatenate the subdocument name with the dot (.) and the field name, and enclose in quotes:
'subdocument.field'